# How to write a PoC of heap-based ROP?

Tags: vulnerability, heap-overflow

I want to write a Proof-of-Concept to exploiting any heap-based vulnerability(e.g. heap overflow, use-after-free) where my ROP(return-to-programming, a kind of code-reuse attacks) payload is deployed on the heap. While such exploits is widespread on windows, counterparts on linux are rare. Could anyone give me any useful advice?

Comment: Umm, you should always be able to edit your own posts. Are you sure you logged in with the same account you used to post the question?

Comment: This is a really undefined question. Googling "rop exploit tutorial" returns a lot of great results.